# Conditional link in a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm building a shop website, I have a button in my home page to proceed to shop page. What I want is that, the button should proceed to my-account page if the user hasn't logged in, and the shop page if he HAS logged in. How do I acheive this?

Right now, I'm adding the following inside the javascript in the page (I'm using a plugin to include the JS)

```
String function getlink()
{
if(is_user_logged_in())
return "/order";
else
return"/my-account"; 
}
document.getElementById('preorder').href = getlink();
```

and I'm specifying the preorder id in the `<a>` as follows:

`<a id="preorder" class="bws-button bws-success bws-radius bws-plane "  href="">`

is there something I'm doing wrong, is there anything extra I need to do? I'm very new to html, JS and wordpress, so elaborate answers are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <a id="preorder" class="bws-button bws-success bws-radius bws-plane "  href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">button for logged in user</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a id="preorder" class="bws-button bws-success bws-radius bws-plane "  href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">button for all</a>
<?php  } ?>
```

add your page id in the permalink area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I kind of need more specific help.
Where is this permalink area? (I've seen the permalink settings)
Where should I add the page ID in it?
Should I add this code just as it is in my page, as I'm not sure how `get_permalink();` will fetch different results based on the condition.

I know I'm asking for probably obvious things, but as I said, I'm VERY new to wordpress.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: In which area that you need to add the login link?

Comment: In the "home" page... As a button

Comment: I tried using  your code and changed the `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` with the actual link hard-coded.. But I'm seeing two buttons.. Its not getting called conditionally .. I highly doubt if php works in the page

Comment: Can you share you website url

Comment: just did an inspect element to find out the problem, the php was getting commented automatically...found a plugin to convert the php snippet into a shortcode so we can insert in the page. Thanks alot for your help :)...really appreciate it :)

Comment: @RoshanAP You shouldn't explain why you edited in the edit itself, that's what the edit summary is there for. If the problem is the 6 character limit, adding a `<!---->` somewhere in the body will solve the problem, since `<!---->` is a comment and is therefore not visible.